# PHP Authentication Library

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, user-registration

I'm trying to implement user login part of my website. I thought it would be much easier just to use a library rather than write a 1000 lines of code to reinvent the wheel. So I'm just trying to get stackoverflow's opinion, what is the best php user login authentication library out there. I've been looking around (usercake, kohana) but a lot of them look like a high-school project by someone rather than a fully supported and developed library. Also, they seem to be using the deprecated mysql injections and I want to use PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `PEAR`[`OpenID`](http://pear.php.net/package/OpenID) package.

Check the other `PEAR`[`Authentication`](http://pear.php.net/packages.php?catpid=1) packages too.

Comment: what is the difference between auth and auth_http?

Comment: @JohnBernal `Auth` provides a full `user management system` with support for different databases and other systems. `Auth_HTTP` merely replicates Apache server's `basic authentication` feature.

Comment: ah okay. So one more thing....i'm having a really hard time following following this tutorial. Is there a way to only call this authentication stuff if the click the `login` button rather than force them to login at the start of the site?

Comment: @JohnBernal if you want to force a login, use `if (!$a->checkAuth()) { //force login or show login link/box } else { //logged in, show user details } `.

Comment: no i said I don't want that. I just want to display my normal webpage, and then if the user clicks login, THEN i want all this auth stuff to run. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: @JohnBernal check the `Using optional authentication` section in the [manual](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.authentication.auth.intro.php). Unless you do `if (!$a->checkAuth()) { // force redirect }`, the user will be able to view the normal webpage.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17323/discussion-between-john-bernal-and-air4x)